# Hindi Poster Underneath a Bench in Anohana

Tags: anohana

I'm re-watching Ano Hana. On the first episode (22:44.438) I noticed a poster underneath a bench.

I recognized it was written in Hindi although I can't read Hindi.
So, was wondering what's written there and what could be it's purpose (the visual detail).

#### Questions:

1. What was the Hindi text and what it means?
2. I hope someone can share some thoughts about why this much details was added into a scene. What could be the creator's intention?

#### Update

The poster can be overlooked because it's underneath. So I've added another picture with more exposure

[image: Original Screenshot]

[[image: Exposure increased[2]]

Comment: I saw your answer before you deleted it, updated my question to clarify. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if it is supposed to be Hindi or Sanskrit(because both use devagiri script) and the word is there in both the languages, The word is 'Dharmayug', which means the age of righteousness or somewhere along that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [sentido's](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/48611/2516) and [Ashray's](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/48610/2516) answer about the meaning of Dharmayug, Dharma and Yug, we can interpret the creator's intention to imply that their friendship was beyond space(cosmos) and time. That's why the poster was put underneath the "Secret base" carving (their "Secret base" friendship was beyond space and time):

1. **Beyond Space**
   Menma was a ghost, the rest of them were human, they should be living in separate world. But their friendship transcended that.
2. **Beyond Time**
   In the story they were repeatedly recalling their childhood memories with Menma, and even some of the scenes were almost the same as their childhood scenes.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if it is supposed to be Hindi or Sanskrit(because both use devagiri script and the word is there in both the languages), The word is 'Dharmayug', which means the age of righteousness or somewhere along that.

Also the word is another word for Satyayug which is one of the 4 ages of the Hindu Mythology. More specifcally the first age. Age of truth.

Not sure as to why the creator put it though.

Comment: Dharmyug likely refers to Hindi pictorial weekly magazine by the same name, published 1949 to 1993.

Comment: Good to know. we got some clue

Answer (score 3):

'Dharmayug'
It is a combination of two words- Dharma + Yug

Dharma stands for eternal law of cosmos, your actions basically. Yug is basically a period of time. As Ashray mentioned, it can be translated to the age of righteousness. I still can't find the symbolism though